# Entity Framework Polymorphic associations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

I'm going to use Entity Framework soon for a Booking System ( made from scratch ).

I have been doing a few Prototypes, trying to figure out what I want to do before the project is started (I'm still discussing requirements etc. with the client).

Consider this case:

I have a Booking, and a booking can have associated Ressources, that can be booked, but these ressource can be different, and have different Fields etc.

[image: ER Diagram of the Relationship]

I have never really used EF before, so I don't know how I can achieve this kind of Polymorphism, that I am use to in other projects (where we have been using raw SQL).

The C# Model would look like this:

```
public class Booking
{
    public int BookingID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public IRessource Ressources { get; set; }
    ...
}

public interface IRessource
{
    public int RessourceTypeId { get; set; }
}

public class Room : IRessource
{
    public int RoomID { get; set; }
    public int RessourceTypeId { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Car : IRessource
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public int RessourceTypeId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Is this achievable, and if yes, then how?
How would the querying even look?

Comment: take a look at this: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx

Comment: As a side note, the correct spelling is "resource", with one "s", not "ressources" with two "s"s.

Comment: @Cupcake, ye I found that out later on ^^

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Yes, absolutely.**

It sounds like you really want a [Table Per Type (TPT)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx) relationship.  This represents the standard `is-a / has-a` foreign key relationships.  Note that by default, Entity Framework utilizes Table Per Hierarchy (TPH).

Here are some links:

- [Table Per Hierarchy
  (TPH)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx)
- [Table Per Type
  (TPT)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx)
- [Table Per Concrete Type (TPC)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx)

I highly recommend you go through some of these links on your own, but the main point to extract is that you use something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IRessource>().ToTable("IRessources");
modelBuilder.Entity<Room>().ToTable("Rooms");
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().ToTable("Cars");
```

Both of which inherit from `IRessource` in your demonstrated code above.  Then, you can do a join between these individual tables and the central `IRessource` table to get all of the information pertaining to the individual entities.

Something like: `SELECT * FROM IRessource i JOIN Room r ON i.id == r.id`

However, you'll often times find that if you use a `Web API` controller, if you just pull the entire `Room` POCO, you'll get all of its properties at once without the join at all!

---

In my experience, I've also found that typically things go smoother if you *do not use interfaces or abstract classes* because if you do, you'll have to make Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) to transfer data occasionally since you can't instantiate objects of those types.  Things can get a little bit messy -- especially if you're not sure exactly what you're doing.  To help you understand, think of a controller with which you want to pass in a generic `IRressource` -- it'll try to convert those objects as it receives them into one which can't be instantiated.  Bummer!  So, the easy solution is just to make both the base class and the inherited classes normal classes.

Comment: Post an update if you have any problems or confusion -- another thing to note is that the subclasses inherit the key from the parent, which isn't illustrated in your original code but it is in the TPT link.

Comment: Hmm.. it doesn't work with interface, which I supposed is acceptable. Trying it out with abstract classes.

Comment: Got it working with abstract classes instead of interface, it makes a direct reference with the Booking as you mentioned, which is wrong, ressources should be static, and be referenced in a mapping table. I wonder how I can achieve that.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your diagram, but wouldn't it be fine if `BookingRessource : Ressource` and then it has a `public virtual Booking Booking` and a `public int BookingId`? Essentially saying, "A booking Ressource is a ressource which has a booking"

Comment: That is the way I want it yes, just need to do some fiddling I guess. But thanks to you I'm well on my way. I will read the links you have supplied, to get a better grasp at it. In the long run, I think EF and the likes is something that I would rather use than raw SQL. Though I have some experience with NHibernate.

Comment: Definitely check out lazy-loading vs. eager-loading too as well as virtual properties.  There's a lot to digest in code-first EF to understand how the magic is happening.

Comment: I am atleast familiar with those concepts, from NHibernate. But thank you, I will.

Comment: The crappy thing about inheritance vs interfaces is that you can't do multiple inheritance.