# Entity Framework Many-Many Polymorphic Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a requirement to store images related to various entities in a database (sorted in a particular order), where the images are selected from a central 'media library'. I'm accessing the data with Entity Framework 6.

The general scenario is there's a central table of images, which users can relate to various entities within the system (e.g. locations can have images, users can have images - a location can re-use the same image used by a user).

In my head, the structure is as below. I'm having trouble figuring out what the implementation would look like as an Entity Framework entity layout.

I've looked at answers such as [Entity Framework Polymorphic associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904582/entity-framework-polymorphic-associations) (Table-Per-Type?) but they seem to take the approach of linking EntityWithMedia1 and EntityWithMedia2 so they are related with a parent table, but this situation doesn't really lend itself to this approach in my opinion (e.g. the two entities happen to both include media, but should remain completely separate in terms of DB structure).

```
Media {
        ImageId (int)
        ImageName (string)
        ImageFileName (string)
        RelatedEntities (list) // Queries RelatedMedia table
}

RelatedMedia {
        ImageId (int)
        EntityWithMediaId (int) // Actual Id of the Entity to be used with Type below
        EntityWithMediaType (string) // In my head this says 'SomeEntity1' or some other ID such as a guid defined on the entity in c# (the 'Laravel approach')
        SortOrder (int)
}

SomeEntity1 {
        SomeEntity1Id (int)
        EntityName (string)
        SomeProperty (int)
        RelatedMedia (list) // Queries RelatedMedia table
} 

SomeEntity2 {
        SomeEntity2Id (int)
        EntityName (string)
        AnotherProperty (string)
        RelatedMedia (list) // Queries RelatedMedia table
}
```

If this isn't supported out of the box, is there much scope to implement this by extending EF (e.g. write my own query so EF knows what to do when I try to use the RelatedEntities/RelatedMedia properties)?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to join objects that don't have a physical relation ( SomeEntity1 / RelatedMedia ), you have to write your join clause, using the `join` keyword.

For instance:

```
var query =
   from media in context.RelatedMedias
   join entity in context.Entities on media.EntityWithMediaId equals entity.SomeEntityId
   where entity.EntityWithMediaType == "EntityType"
   select new { Media = media, Entity = entity };
```

If you want to load for a specific object:

```
var entity;
var medias = context.RelatedMedias.Where(i => i.EntityWithMediaType == "EntityType" && i.EntityWithMediaId == entity.EntityId);
```