# In Entity Framework, how do you define a "selective" one-to-one relationship (one-to-one of many)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How do you define a relationship where a model consists of, or has a relationship with only one of many models it could relate to? For instance, I’m developing a simple Service Desk. Each Incident, Problem, Change, Release or Service Request is linked to a single ticket. Each Problem can also relate to many Incidents.

```
public class Incident
{
    public virtual Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    public virtual Problem Problem { get; set; }
}

public class Problem
{
    public virtual Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Incident> Incidents { get; set; }
}

public class Change
{
    public virtual Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
}

public class Release
{
    public virtual Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceRequest
{
    public virtual Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
}

public class Ticket
{
   //I thought about adding virtual properties for each ticket type, but that implies that each ticket can consist of all 5 types at once
}
```

However, each ticket can only relate to one of the five ticket types. That is, each ticket can share a primary key with either an Incident, Problem, Change etc. (a “selective” one-to-one of many relation, if I may put it that way).

**How do I define this?**

Comment: This sounds like a textbook case of a polymorphic association. You'll have to figure out which table structure works best for your application, but that's the search term you need. Consider this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904582/entity-framework-polymorphic-associations

Comment: Ahh, TPT, thats exactly what I need! Thanks.